# Javascript async waiting for pressing a button. Best practice?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, button

I'd like to run a function and wait in-between for pressing a button before continuing. Is this a good way to do it?

Code:

```js
var demoStart = false;
var demoSleep = true;

async function demoInc() {
  console.log("pressed!");
  if (!demoStart) {
    console.log("Starting... ");
    demoStart = true;
    demo();
  } else {
    console.log("demoSleep ---> FALSE ");
    demoSleep = false;
  }
}

async function demo() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    doStuff(i);

    while (true) {
      console.log("waiting..." + demoSleep);
      if (!demoSleep) {
        console.log("Get out of here!");
        demoSleep = true;
        break;
      }
      await sleep(100);
    }
  }
  //start demo again
  demoStart = false;
}

function doStuff(i) {
  console.log(i);
  var node = document.getElementById("output");
  node.innerHTML = i;
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p id="output">0</p>
  <button onclick="demoInc()">Next</button>

</body>
```

Comment: It works, but whats the use case of doing it so complicatedly? What's your actual question?

Comment: Hi Yoshi, 
I try to have a function which runs till the end, updates the html-code, interrupts and is waiting to continue until pressing a button. I found this solution. My question is, if this is the way to do it or if there's a much more elegant way to realize?